# getCanonicalPath doesn't match with getAbosolutePath

Tags: android

I have an application where i am downloading a zip file into a certain folder. Then i am trying to unzip the same. The getAbsolutePath() method and getCanonicalPath() method doesn't match, though there is no "../". Can someone guide me on this

/data/data/myapppackagename/files/assets/lang100temp/multilang- canonical path

/data/user/0/myapppackagename/files/assets/lang100temp/multilang- absolute path

I have tried using getPath() method, but that is also not matching with the getCanonicalPath() result

Comment: Why would you expect them to match?

Comment: To handle as per this suggestion https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9294009

Comment: If it doesn't match then every time, the code would through security exception

Comment: That code is not comparing `getAbsolutePath()` and `getCanonicalPath()`. `getAbsolutePath()` does not appear anywhere on that page.

Comment: Just unzip in the one and then look in the other to see your file.

Comment: The code has comparing the canonical path with the DIR. In my case DIR is the absolute path that i am tryin to unzip my file into